# I can't get a kml file loaded with ge plugin to move to the last lat/lon

Tags: javascript, geospatial, google-earth-plugin

I have a web page that loads a kml file for viewing using the Google Earth ge plugin. The file loads and displays fine. However, I can get the plugin to move to a lat/lon at the end of the file. The load always leaves the camera at the lat/lon that corresponds to the end point of the kml file.

Here's the code:

```
var ge;

google.load("earth", "1");
google.load("maps", "2");

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
}

function initCallback(instance) {
  ge = instance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
  ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(ge.SPEED_TELEPORT);

  var url = 'http://rallyroadie.org/wordpress/ge/vladi_finish.kml';
  google.earth.fetchKml(ge, url, finished);
}

function finished(object) {
  if (!object) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Bad or null KML.');
    }, 0);
    return;
  }
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(object);

  var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

  // Set new latitude and longitude values.
  lookAt.setLatitude(43.023157);
  lookAt.setLongitude(131.853040);

  // Update the view in Google Earth.
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
}

function failureCallback(errorCode) {
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```

You can see the page at http://rallyroadie.org/wordpress/ge/vladi.html

TIA,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to know how to set the initial view? If so:

You are currently setting it with this code -

```
  var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

  // Set new latitude and longitude values.
  lookAt.setLatitude(43.023157);
  lookAt.setLongitude(131.853040);

  // Update the view in Google Earth.
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

Try playing with different Latitude and Longitude numbers and you will see the difference.
You can also use stuff like lookAt.setRange, lookAt.setTilt and lookAt.setAltitude

See [this link](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control) for more details

It has nothing to do with the .kml file you loaded.